# Continue java stream after collection

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list, I would like to filter using stream, grab the first 10, and display to user.
After a button press.. I would like to continue the stream from that location.

```
List<MyObject> allResults = getResults();
allResults.stream()
    .filter(this::someCrazyFiltering)
    .limit(10)
    .map(this::turnToDisplayItem)
    .forEach(this::addDisplayItemToContainer);

// some stuff..
onClick(() -> {
    List<MyObject> allResults = getResults();
    allResults.stream()
        .filter(this::someCrazyFiltering)
        .skip(10) // will eventually be 10 * amount of times clicked.
        .limit(10)
        .map(this::turnToDisplayItem)
        .forEach(this::addDisplayItemToContainer);
});
```

But the problem is, here I am having to run the filter on the first 10 + how ever many do not match the filter (again).

So far, a few solutions I have is using peek to store the index of the last item, and do a (pre-skip).

```
List<MyObject> allResults = getResults();
allResults.stream()
    .filter(this::someCrazyFiltering)
    .limit(10)
    .peek(o -> this.storeIndex(o, allResults)) // This feels klunky
    .map(this::turnToDisplayItem)
    .forEach(this::addDisplayItemToContainer);

onClick(() -> {
    List<MyObject> allResults = getResults();
    allResults.stream()
        .skip(this.storedIndexToSkip) // This being stored from storeIndex function above.
        .filter(this::someCrazyFiltering)
        .limit(10)
        .peek(o -> this.storeIndex(o, allResults)) // Store again for next click; This STILL feels klunky
        .map(this::turnToDisplayItem)
        .forEach(this::addDisplayItemToContainer);
});
```

I know there is no such thing as an "index" in a stream, So I would need to do `allResults.indexOf(o)` inside the `storeIndex` function, (then will be distinct items)

but if anyone can think of a better mechanism for this? Like being able to splinter off a stream after the `filter`/`limit`??

Or just ignoring streams all together and just going back to good old for-each loop and storing `i` once 10 have been found?

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Where does `getResults()` get the data from? There's nothing wrong with using a `for` loop. It's a lot better than trying to force the stream api everywhere.

Comment: It was unimportant, That is why I just psudocoded it as `getResults()`. Another idea was to just have a iterator I would keep trying to get stuff from until 10 things match or I've hit the end.. but I have no idea if there would be problems having an iterator staying "alive" for a while or not?

Comment: It is important. If you're working with 10000 rows of database data vs. 100 rows of some in-memory data, it makes a huge difference on what you should be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could transform your stream to an iterator and call next() 10 times. The Iterator will get evaluated lazy on each next() call.

```
List<MyObject> allResults = getResults();
Iterator<DisplayItem> it = allResults.stream()
    .filter(this::someCrazyFiltering)
    .map(this::turnToDisplayItem)
    .iterator();

onClick(() -> {
    int n = 0;
    while(n < 10 && it.hasNext()){
       this.addDisplayItemToContainer(it.next());
    }
});
```

Comment: I didn't realise you could mix both a stream AND an iterator.. I was mentioning iterators in the comments, but I wasn't a massive fan of doing it due to the hassle of filtering and mapping. This is the best of both worlds. Thank you.